# Updating element of dataframe while referencing column name and row number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am coming from an R background and used to being able to retrieve the value from a dataframe by using syntax like:

```
r_dataframe$some_column_name[row_number]
```

And I can assign a value to the dataframe by the following syntax:

```
r_dataframe$some_column_name[row_number] <= some_value
```

or without the arrow:

```
r_dataframe$some_column_name[row_number] = some_value
```

For example:

```
#create R dataframe data
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

#print out the name of this employee
employ.data$employee[2]

#assign the name
employ.data$employee[2] <= 'Some other name'
```

I'm now learning some Python and from what I can see the most straight-forward way to retreive a value from a pandas dataframe is:

```
pandas_dataframe['SomeColumnName'][row_number]
```

I can see the similarities to R.

However, what confuses me is that when it comes to modifying/assigning the value in the pandas dataframe I need to completely change the syntax to something like:

```
pandas_dataframe.at[row_number, 'SomeColumnName'] = some_value
```

To read this code is going to require a lot more concentration because the column name and row number have changed order.

Is this the only way to perform this pair of operations? Is there a more logical way to do this that respects the consistent use of column name and row number order?

Comment: kindly provide concrete examples to make sense of your question. possibly a data of a couple of rows. As a side note, it is best to use the `.loc` or `.iloc` notation. Easy to set and retrieve values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean correctly, as @sammywemmy mentioned you can use `.loc` and `.iloc` to get/change value in any row and column.
If the order of your dataframe rows changes, you must define `index` to get every row (datapoint) by its index, even if the order has changed.

Like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['time', 'date', 'name'])
```

Now you can get the first row by its index:

```
df.loc['a']     # equivalent to df.iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `pandas_dataframe.at[row_number, 'SomeColumnName']` can be used to modify AND retrieve information.